# How do I process every row in a table through a called procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure I am trying to run with data that has been loaded in another table. I had tried creating a trigger on update that passed the new.variables into the procedure, and it worked record by record, but that did not work on a group update.

Now I have tried creating a procedure that scrolls through each record in the table but I cannot get it to work.

This is what the body of my procedure looks like.  It appears to stop on the first run through. To debug I added a select statement before the call which crashed the procedure but indicated it has made it to the call statement.

Is this the correct way to step through a database from beginning to end in a stored procedure?

Has anyone written a simple procedure which calls a row of data from a table, runs the data in the columns through a stored procedure, and then continues in this manner through the entire table?

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE t1 INT default 0;
DEclARE t2 INT default 0;
DECLARE p1 VARCHAR(2) default ' '; 
DEclARE p2 VARCHAR(2)  default ' ';
DECLARE st INT default 0;
DECLARE sp INT default 0;
DECLARE ce VARCHAR(2)  default ' ';
DECLARE sd INT default 0;
Declare sgid int;
DECLARE Get_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM segments WHERE 1;  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 
OPEN Get_cur;  
set done = False;
lbl: LOOP  
    FETCH Get_cur INTO sgid, CE, ST, SP, T1, T2, P1, P2;
    IF done then 
        LEAVE lbl;  
    END IF;  
    CALL STR_COUNT(T1,T2,P1,P2,ST,SP,CE);
END LOOP;  
  
CLOSE Get_cur; 
END
```

If it is of interest this is my segment database:

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Comments    Extra
1   SEGIDIndex  int(9)          No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   ChromeIndex varchar(2)  utf8_general_ci     No  None        
3   strtIndex   int(9)          No  None        
4   stpIndex    int(9)          No  None        
5   TESTID1Index    int(2)          No  None        
6   TESTID2Index    int(2)          No  None        
7   Path1   varchar(1)  utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL        
8   Path2   varchar(1)  utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL        
Indexes
```

Procedure str count:

```
BEGIN
/* This first section updates tester1's path is null but tester2's path is not null and tester1 has an allele that matches tester2's path*/
CASE 
/* Cases based on the path for each tester*/
WHEN pa1="m" and pa2="m" THEN 
    /* In this case both paths are maternal */
    UPDATE      
        alleles a       
    JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
    LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
    ON      
    a.rsid = b.Rsid     
    SET     
    a.maternal = b.maternal,a.phased=1
    WHERE
    a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.maternal is null) and (b.maternal=a.allele1 or b.maternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa1="m" and pa2="p" THEN 
    UPDATE      
    alleles a       
    JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
    LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
    ON      
    a.rsid = b.Rsid     
    SET     
    a.maternal = b.paternal,a.phased=1
    WHERE
    a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.maternal is null) and (b.paternal=a.allele1 or b.paternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa1="p" and pa2="m" THEN 
    UPDATE      
    alleles a       
    JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
    LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
    ON      
    a.rsid = b.Rsid     
    SET     
    a.paternal = b.maternal,a.phased=1
    WHERE
    a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.paternal is null) and (b.maternal=a.allele1 or b.maternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa1="p" and pa2="m" THEN 
    UPDATE      
    alleles a       
    JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
    LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
    ON      
    a.rsid = b.Rsid     
    SET     
    a.paternal = b.paternal,a.phased=1
    WHERE
    a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.paternal is null) and (b.paternal=a.allele1 or b.paternal=a.allele2);
END CASE;
CASE 
/* Cases based on the path for each tester now updating tester2
first switch path lines*/

WHEN pa2="m" and pa1="m" THEN 
/* In this case both paths are maternal */
UPDATE      
alleles a       
JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
ON      
a.rsid = b.Rsid     
SET     
a.maternal = b.maternal, a.phased=1
WHERE
/*here is where tester 1 and 2 are differentiated */
a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.maternal is null) and (b.maternal=a.allele1 or b.maternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa2="m" and pa1="p" THEN 
UPDATE      
alleles a       
JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
ON      
a.rsid = b.Rsid     
SET     
a.maternal = b.paternal, a.phased=1
WHERE
a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.maternal is null) and (b.paternal=a.allele1 or b.paternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa2="p" and pa1="m" THEN 
UPDATE      
alleles a       
JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
ON      
a.rsid = b.Rsid     
SET     
a.paternal = b.maternal, a.phased=1
WHERE
a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.paternal is null) and (b.maternal=a.allele1 or b.maternal=a.allele2);
WHEN pa2 ="p" and pa1="p" THEN 
UPDATE      
alleles a       
JOIN rsids ON rsids.rsid = a.rsid       
LEFT OUTER JOIN alleles AS b        
ON      
a.rsid = b.Rsid     
SET     
a.paternal = b.paternal, a.phased=1
WHERE
a.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t2) AND b.testid = (SELECT testid FROM individuals WHERE individuals.tester = t1) AND (rsids.position BETWEEN strt AND stp and rsids.chrome=c and a.phased=0 and a.paternal is null) and (b.paternal=a.allele1 or b.paternal=a.allele2);
END CASE;
END

Some segment data

SELECT * FROM `segments`
SEGID  Chrome     strt     stp     TESTID1     TESTID2   Path1    Path2
6       1        3677933 13176463     1           10         m        m
7       1       13775122 41880343     1           10         m        m
8       2       30118211 41802979     1           10         m        m
```

Comment: post ample data for segments  ans also the second stored and alos explain what doesn't work exactly

Comment: to reproduce your problem,of we still don't know nothing about, we must debug your code, which only works, if we have the data for seqments and also the stored procedure STR_COUNT

Comment: I can provide that, but it works fine when I call it from a trigger one record at a time, and when I call it from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the example, this works just fine, but the debugging, is much more complicated

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`cust_id` int, `Product_id` varchar(1), `Order_date` datetime,myint int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`cust_id`, `Product_id`, `Order_date`,myint)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'a', '2020-10-02 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (2, 'b', '2020-10-01 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (3, 'c', '2020-09-07 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (4, 'd', '2020-09-02 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (1, 'a', '2020-08-29 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (1, 'f', '2020-08-02 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (2, 'g', '2020-07-01 02:00:00', NULL),
>     (3, 't', '2020-06-06 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (4, 'j', '2020-05-08 02:00:00',NULL),
>     (1, 'w', '2020-04-20 02:00:00',NULL)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE procedure UPDATEme(_cust_id int, _Product_id varchar(4), _Order_date DATETIME)
> BEGIN 
>
> UPDATE tab1 SET myint = 1 
> WHERE `cust_id` = _cust_id AND  `Product_id` = Product_id AND  `Order_date` = _Order_date;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CREATE procedure t1()
> BEGIN 
>   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   DECLARE _Order_date DATETIME ;
>   DECLARE _cust_id INT; 
>   DECLARE _Product_id varchar(4);
>
>   -- declare cursor for employee email
>   DEClARE curlo 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT `cust_id`, `Product_id`, `Order_date` FROM tab1;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>
>   OPEN curlo;
>
>   getDat: LOOP
>       FETCH curlo INTO _cust_id, _Product_id, _Order_date;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getDat;
>       END IF;
>
>       -- build email list
>       CALL UPDATEme(_cust_id, _Product_id, _Order_date);
>   END LOOP getDat;
>   CLOSE curlo;
> end
> ```

> ```
> CALL t1();
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> cust_id | Product_id | Order_date          | myint
> ------: | :--------- | :------------------ | ----:
>       1 | a          | 2020-10-02 02:00:00 |     1
>       2 | b          | 2020-10-01 02:00:00 |     1
>       3 | c          | 2020-09-07 02:00:00 |     1
>       4 | d          | 2020-09-02 02:00:00 |     1
>       1 | a          | 2020-08-29 02:00:00 |     1
>       1 | f          | 2020-08-02 02:00:00 |     1
>       2 | g          | 2020-07-01 02:00:00 |     1
>       3 | t          | 2020-06-06 02:00:00 |     1
>       4 | j          | 2020-05-08 02:00:00 |     1
>       1 | w          | 2020-04-20 02:00:00 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b497bc4f1221d9c99dbf87172e3948e2)*

This shows that ot runs smotthly.

But your code has update with 4 or AND WHERE Clause so i am guessing, that your conditions a renot met.

I startet a fiddle with your code https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=130566dac971caf87f24979e3412d54d

you can add more data to test it

Comment: Is it possible the call stmt is not getting rebuilt each time? Do I need to use an execute or prepare stmt instead?  I have tried over and over issuing my str_count procedure using the different values in my segment database and it works fine. It is just when I use the second procedure to step through the variables that it doesnt work.  I also noticed that when I ran it in Phpmyadmin the quotes around the variables were not allowable but when I ran it with DBeaver the quotes were required around string characters. Is that going to affect the call stmt?

Comment: usually this is a sign,that you sent different data. what you can do is add for every value in count a SET @a1 = T1 amd so on and set stratigic further user define variables and you can take the second fiddle and add your´r table and data for further testing

Comment: Thank you. I did find my error and it works perfectly now.